# Why do I need to dispose a postgresql sqlalchemy engine?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

```
>>> import subprocess, sqlalchemy
>>> engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgresql+psycopg://myuser:secret@localhost/mydb")
>>> subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/dropdb', '-U', 'myuser', 'mydb'])
dropdb: database removal failed: ERROR:  database "openstack_citest" is being accessed by other users                                                        
DETAIL:  There are 1 other session(s) using the database.
```

I checked which user is using the database and it's the user that's trying to drop it.

I can solve this by issuing an `engine.dispose()` call, but I don't know why. There shouldn't be any open connections to the database in the first place.

Trying the same thing with `mysql` as the backend works without the `dispose()` call works just fine to drop the database.

Answer (score 3):

That's by [design](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-dropdatabase.html):

> DROP DATABASE drops a database. [...]. Also, it cannot be executed
>   while you or anyone else are connected to the target database

Comment: But I'm not connected to any database. I didn't do engine.connect(). So does sqlalchemy create a connection when initializing the engine?